# IOS7 - Xcode5 - Memory Leaks with NO CODE

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

first of all, sorry for my english. Now, i've made a simple app in Xcode 5, with a TabBar Controller and a Navigation Bar Controller embed in it. When i run the app with profile i see some leaks (32bytes) that appear when the app goes in background mode. This happen only when i use to embed Navigation Controller in Tab Bar Controller, even if i don't write any single line of code. in stack trace the only function for the leaks is in main.m.

How is it possible?

The type of leak is:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
__NSCFString    1   0x17530290  32 Bytes    Foundation  -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you need to be worrying about. This looks like either a false positive (as Instruments is prone to give) or some minor memory leak on Apple's part. It's not going to affect you negatively in a way that demands your attention.

Comment: Oh, false positive! My god, i'm typing code and making new projects from about 24 hours to find a solution. My god!

Comment: For 64 bytes?! This isn't the '60s ;)

Comment: 64 + 64 + 64... 64 every one minute in 12 days will get a MegaByte. LOL

Comment: This was really useful to read. I've spent all day trying to figure out why my app is randomly leaking memory (from all different libs/classes, none of which I have touched) when there is no code to leak! I finally tried shutting down instrument and Xcode and then when I re-open them there are no memory leaks.

Comment: Do you profile with iPhone Simulator? Use iPhone device instead.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks dont just happen, Xcode is a derp. Turn it off and on again and it will work like a charm.